# Aligning text of a table with the body text

Tags: tables, align, indentation

I am trying to align the text in a table with the body text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Lorum impsum

D \\
%not the actual forced alignment
\hskip-0.1cm\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{7cm}}
Dynamic & is not static \\ \\
Static  & is not dynamic
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to align D of the body with the Dynamic of the table without using some brutish \hskip with hard coded values for a forced alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the inter/extra-column space to the left of the tabular by inserting "nothing": add `@{}` at the beginning of the column specifiers. Note that the `D` before the table in your document is itself not aligned with the body text, since it starts a paragraph and therefore by default is indented by `\parindent`. Use `\noindent` to start paragraphs at the left margin (or switch off paragraph indentation for the whole document).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
D \\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm}p{7cm}}
Dynamic & is not static \\
Static  & is not dynamic
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]